# C++ Classes and Overloaded Operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have been trying to make a `StringTable` class that holds a simple `unordered_map<string, string>`, and has the array index operator '[]' overloaded to work for accessing the map; however, the compiler will tell me that I have yet to define the overloaded operator when I try to use it. My code is as follows:

#### CStringTable.h

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

class CStringTable {
public:
    bool Load(const char* filename);

    inline const char* operator [](const char* key);

    const char* Get(const char* key);

private:
    std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>* m_StringMap;
};
```

#### CStringTable.cpp

```
#include "CStringTable.h"

inline const char* CStringTable::operator [](const char* key) {
    std::string sKey = key;

    return (*m_StringMap)[sKey].c_str();
}
```

I try to access the map as follows:

```
(*m_cStringTable)[msgKey]
```

where `m_cStringTable` is a pointer to an instance of the `CStringTable` class and `msgKey` is a `const char*`.

Can anybody enlighten me as to why this won't work?

Comment: Did you get error? Please specify if so.

Comment: This works fine for me, so posting the exact error you're getting would definitely help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the inline keyword, the compiler needs to be able to see the body of that method as well in the .h file. So either move the implementation of the operator from the .cpp file to the .h file, or include the body of the operator in the class declaration.

Comment: Ahh yes, this appears to have fixed the problem. Either removing the inline keyword or moving the declaration to the .h file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type unordered_map has not the operator [] defined. Are you sure you can access the element of the map with that operator?

Comment: I do so in my Get() function that should ahve the same functionality, and that function seems to work. The code is literally copy and pasted.

const char* CStringTable::Get(const char* key) {
 std::string sKey = key;

 return (*m_StringMap)[sKey].c_str();
}

Comment: Aw so this is where this library come from : )
Are you sure you really need it?

Comment: I actually have it through MinGW gcc anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, per spec of unordered_map:

> If inserting an element causes
>   unordered_map::load_factor() to exceed
>   the maximum load factor, the container
>   increases the number of buckets and
>   rebuilds the hash table as needed.

I'm not sure about engine of reallocation, but seems string would be copied by value. 
This mean that when you return const char * - in fact it can be erased by container reallocation. So pointer is unsafe and non-const.

On other hand (for example usual std::map) grants that tree is stable relative insert/remove operators and memory pointers of std::string are stable

Comment: How would this cause a compiler error about overloading `[]`?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek I've asked to provide compiler error. Since I didn't get it I begin "sniffing" what else wrong with this code. My point with reallocation looks reasonable, isn't?

Comment: I've no idea if this is right, but if it doesn't answer his question you shouldn't post it as an answer; it's a comment